# Validar limite de caracteres

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de validar en un div la cantidad de caracteres que seria 30, pero al momento de pegar contenido nuevo cuando son 29 caracteres YA NO RESPETA LA LIMITACIÓN.

```js
function limitar(e, contenido, caracteres) {
            var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

            if (unicode == 8 || unicode == 46 || unicode == 13 || unicode == 9 || unicode == 37 || unicode == 39 || unicode == 38 || unicode == 40)
                return true;

            if (contenido.length >= caracteres) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


$(".hijo").on("paste", function(e){
 if($(".hijo").text().length == 30){
     e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    if($(".hijo").text().length < 30){
     $(".hijo").text().substring(0,4);
    }
});
```

```css
.container{
 background: orange;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="hijo" contentEditable=true onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">Contenido</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**ADEMÁS**

Lo he intentado con "DOMSubtreeModified" y NO hay resultado.

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified','.hijo',function(){
if($(".hijo").text().length < 30){
    $(".hijo").text().substring(0,30);
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas tambien tomar en cuenta la longitud del texto que vas a pegar.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function limitar(e, contenido, caracteres) {
            var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

            if (unicode == 8 || unicode == 46 || unicode == 13 || unicode == 9 || unicode == 37 || unicode == 39 || unicode == 38 || unicode == 40)
                return true;

            if (contenido.length >= caracteres) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


$(".hijo").on("paste", function(e){
    var texto = $(".hijo").text() + e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    if(texto.length >= 30){
     e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    if($(".hijo").text().length < 30){
     $(".hijo").text().substring(0,4);
    }
});
```

```css
.container{
 background: orange;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="hijo" contentEditable=true onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">Contenido</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm, disculpa por la pregunta, pero que es lo que esta haciendo exactamente el substring(0,4), sé que esta obteniendo los 4 primeros caracteres , pero no entiendo bien en como funciona con el paste.

Comment: Creo que no lo necesitas.

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm por tu tiempo ;)